# referencing json data in datatables - howto

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have an external json file as follows (fake data);

```
{
 "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
   ]
}
```

I call the table like below and, as expected it works;

```
    let myPeople=      $('#myPeople_index').DataTable({                  
        ajax:           '/user_public/people/data/myPeople.txt',
        dataType:       'json', 
        "columns": [
            {"data":"name"},
        ]   
    });
```

I want to change the array name in the json file to `properties` and so have revised above as follows;

```
    let myPeople=      $('#myPeople_index').DataTable({     
        data:           'properties',   
        ajax:           '/user_public/people/data/myPeople.txt',
        dataType:       'json', 
        "columns": [
            {"properties": "name"},
        ]   
    });
```

and change the datafile to;

```
{
 "properties": [
    {
      "id": "1",
```

I get an error as follows;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') 
datatables.min.js:77
```

I have tried to read the man pages here https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Objects  but I am certainly missing something.  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't your browser block your attempted local text file access with a CORS error, for the example which is working already for you? (I'm surprised it works).

Comment: Also, side note: Your `dataType: 'json'` option will be ignored, since it's not inside the `ajax` option. I would expect to see `ajax: { ajax options here }, ... `.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. The description of the JSON tag: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals. Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)."_

Comment: @jabaa I have removed the comma on line 19.  That was me shortening the sample for a long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let myPeople=      $('#myPeople_index').DataTable({     
        data:           'properties',   
        ajax:           '/user_public/people/data/myPeople.txt',
        dataType:       'json', 
        "columns": [
            {"properties": "name"},
        ]   
    });
```

should be

```
let myPeople=      $('#myPeople_index').DataTable({     
        ajax: {
          url: '/user_public/people/data/myPeople.txt',
          dataSrc: 'properties'
        }
        dataType:       'json', 
        "columns": [
            {"data": "name"},
        ]   
    });
```

`data` is not a key in your data, it's a specific property in the API.

Comment: Thank you Jabaa.  Read more and learnt more.  Silly mistakes but thanks.